# i want each user to be able to add data with their id, so when they log in they can only view data that they added

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

the code works fine when it is only one user but once i create a second user, the data doesn't get inserted into the database

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO images ( users_id, picture, Carehome, dateworked, hours) 
    VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users  ), '$target_file', '$Carehome', '$dateworked', '$hours')";
```

Comment: The subquery `(SELECT id FROM users  )` returns *all* the IDs in the table. You can only use a query that returns a single value there. Why don't you just put the logged in user's ID into a session variable, and use that?

Comment: Also make sure that the values of `$target_file`, `$Carehome`, `$dateworked` and `$hours` don't come from the user. In this case your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: i think that is the problem, it returns all IDS. How do i write the command to  put the logged in user's ID into a session variable?

Answer (score 0):

You call all users ID

> SELECT id FROM users

You can solve it by get it id by id

```
<?php
$sql_ids = "SELECT id FROM users";
//get users row by row
//your_db_conn is example you must replace it by your variable 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(your_db_conn,$sql_ids))){
//save user id in $id
    $id = $row['id'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO images ( users_id, picture, Carehome, dateworked, hours) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$target_file', '$Carehome', '$dateworked','$hours')";
    mysqli_query(your_db_conn,$sql);
}
?>
```

**Make sure user id is not a primary key in images table**